# Getting a member of a pointer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have an `TObject` called `Target2` that is a pointer to say `TLabel` and would like to get the property `Name` from this pointer.  Thus I have this

```
Procedure TGetName()
var
  Item : TLabel;
Begin
  if Target2 is TLabel then
  begin
     Item := Target2;
     if Item.Name := 'SomeName' then
       begin
        ....
       dosomething();
       end;
  end;
end;
```

But it seem pointless to have `Item` now become a pointer to a pointer but when I do:

```
Procedure TGetName()
Begin
  if Target2 is TLabel then
   begin
      if Target2.Name := 'SomeName' then
         begin
          ....
         dosomething();
         end;
    end;
end;
```

I get errror that name is not a member of `Target2`.  Thus how do I access this without creating another pointer to the pointer `Target2`?

Comment: Try this `(Target2 as TLabel).Name := 'SomeName'`

Comment: What pointers you are talking about??

Comment: Thanks lqbal that works, @MBo i was talking about two pointers in the question, but only wanted 1. `Target2` (i wanted) `Item` (i did not want)

Comment: Well, your second example shows why it's not a bad idea to have the local Item variable.  In the long run, that will avoid having to do things like "with Target2 as TLabel do ..." and will make your code easier to debug.

Comment: @martynA my consern about having the second var was the process of destroying it,  First not sure i have to because it was just a pointer. And well i never really created.. but if it needed to be, this could be an headache as i would think it would destroy the actual component.. anyhow.  Thanks for answer

Comment: @GlennMorse:  Well, if you point a local variable like your Item at an object like Target2, you wouldn't want to do an Item.Free unless you're intending to free Target2.  Maybe think of it this way:  If you assign Item to Target2, all you're doing is pointing it at it, so no new object has been created, and so nothing needs Free()ing when you're done with Item.

Comment: @MBo - for 'pointer' read 'reference'

Comment: I'm fine with calling these things pointers. That's what they are. They aren't references like in C++.

Comment: @Chris Rolliston I was confused by 'pointer to pointer' in context of usual object reference's casting

Comment: @MBo - sure, that's just incorrect

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - OTOH I would explain reference types by saying they are ultimately pointers; OTO the term 'pointers' in Delphi refers to a distinct kind of type that involves its own special syntax (i.e., the @ and ^ symbols, and in the case of typed pointers, pointer maths) that doesn't apply to reference types. As such, in a Delphi context it is better to use the term 'pointer' in the more restricted sense, though it's no big deal if a questioner doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to cast. If you are prepared to assert the `Target2` is a `TLabel` then use a checked cast:

```
var
  Lbl: TLabel;
....
Lbl := Target2 as TLabel;
```

Otherwise check using `is` and then an unchecked cast is fine:

```
if Target2 is TLabel then
begin
  Lbl := TLabel(Target2);
  ....
```

You don't need to destroy `Lbl` because it is just a reference to an object that is owned by somebody else.